# Move/Displace Marker Coords for showing extra information on Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a few Makers into my Map using Google Maps API v3. They are located by a LAT and LONG coords, and show default marker (A, B, C).

But now I want to show for each marker another marker displaced (or moved) a few pixels from default maker, 
like this image:

[image: Moved from the original coords square]

The square must be a small div coloured.

How I must write the new Marker?

Comment: Why recreate the wheel.  Have you seen [MarkerWithLabel](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.0.1/examples/basic.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markers cannot be created from DOM-elements(e.g. div's).

You must create [a custom overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays)

[MarkerWithLabel](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/docs/reference.html) should be a good choice to achieve it.